# Add some list to feuser on back end

Tags: typo3

[feuser edit page screenshoote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUgTl.png)[Screenshote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQKJS.png)

Hello, everybody. Can somebody tell me how I can add some list to feuser page on back end? Like it shown on screenshot(list with users). I want to add similar tab with user comments to feuser edit page on back end. So I want to show so user comments. Don't advice other variants please, tell me please how to do it please, if is it possible.

I want to add my table to user edit page, see screenshot, and show rows which relate to this user

TYPO3 7.6.16

Comment: I would think the method `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages()` in your ext_tables.php could make it, but I cannot test it right now.

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much! But what params I must pass to this method ? I see that I can pass $table, but how I can set exactly edit page where I want show my list ?

Comment: You have to set the table from your comments records. At least this method makes it possible to add records on standard pages (not only sys folder). Then you need some records on a standard page and have a look.

Comment: yes you right. Thank you! But it not give me ability to add some list to user edit page on back end ) Really don't know how to do it ( It would be very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any table to Web module page view, via ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['cms']['db_layout']['addTables']['tx_myext_domain_model_name'] = [
    'default' => [
        'MENU' => 'LLL:EXT:tx_myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:menuDefault',
        'fList' =>  'title,description,image',
        'icon' => TRUE
    ]
];
```

Clear cache, and your done. Adapt listed fields (fList) depend on your needs.

Comment: Man, thank great thank you! Just tell me please, how I can set that my table will be shown exactly on fe_user edit page ? I think I should set it somewhere in this array $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['cms']['db_layout']['addTables']['tx_myext_domain_model_name']

Comment: $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['cms']['db_layout']['addTables'][$_EXTKEY][0]['fList'] = 'uid,title,author,category,datetime,archivedate,tstamp';

may be like that ? Can you help me. please ?

Comment: Insert your table name as defined in your SQL for tx_myex‌​t_domain_model_name

Comment: And yes, fList can be any field as defined in your SQL for your table

Comment: ok, this array I should put to ext_tables.php to femanager ? or my extension?

Comment: In your extension. Don't change thirdparty extensions loaded from TER, to be able to update to future fixes and releases.

Comment: I just can't understand how it will be add table to feuser edit page ? I think I have specify the feuser module or something like that

Comment: It just add a listing at the bottom in the page module in your TYPO3 backend, with your defined fields from your defined table. This listing is only  visible, if your table has entries within the current page you selected in page tree. Thats why you can see fe_users listet at your feuser storage page.

Comment: It really working, but I want to add my table to user edit page, see screenshot (I added new picture to head), and show rows which relate to this user

Comment: Be aware, that you asked for a solution to list your comments in TYPO3 backend web module which called 'Page', see your first screenshot ('Screenshote'). Your second screenshot ('feuser edit page screenshoote') shows TYPO3 backend with another web module called 'List', which differs from 'Page'. Web module 'List' is able to list entries which are stored at the selected page, if you use 'allowTab‌​leOnStandardPages' as Thomas Löffler mentioned earlier this day.

Comment: Thank you! I have field image with image name, can I show image in this table ?

Comment: I think, this listing shows only field values from defined table. Only listings in TYPO3 backend web module 'List' are able to evaluate field configurations from table configration array (TCA) and render images or user functions or related values from other tables.